# How to do I update rows of particular user in Flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query that filter out of user data and have to update periodically if any new changes arrives

```
@api.route('/updateUser')
def update_user():
    newUpdate = ['ABC-123', 'DCS-344', 'FDC-473','HJG-297']
   
    name = "name1"
    user = User.query.filter_by(user = name).all()
    # user Ouput: ['ABC-123', 'BCD-23', 'DCS-344']
    try:
       for i in newUpdate:
         data = User(user =name, ID=i)
         rows_updated =User.query.filter_by(name=name).update(ID=i))
         db.session.add(rows_updated)
         db.session.commit()
         print("User record updated successfully!")
    except:
       print("Something went wrong! - Not updated")
```

Present output:

```
user          ID
name1     ABC-123
name1     BCD-233
name1     DCS-344
name2     ABE-113
name2     BCS-776
name3     RTD-445
name3     UTR-554
```

Desired output:

```
user          ID
name1     ABC-123
name1     BCD-233
name1     DCS-344
name1     FDC-473  *
name1     HJG-297  *
name2     ABE-113
name2     BCS-776
name3     RTD-445
name3     UTR-554
```

Here * is the newly updated record for the name1, when this update_user() function triggers it should update the name1 record.

- old ID should not get delete
- it should verify if the same ID present in the db and if the ID is not there in user table then those values should get update.

Can someone help with the above code? I have tried lot of online available resources regarding updating the values but didn't find one? I'm still in learning stage.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're filtering every for loop? Just check your first query for is it exits and add to session.

You can't update any row in that table because you had same name's. How do you know which row will update? Your condition just name and you had multiple same name's.

Without updating you can just add new users like that:

```
   for i in newUpdate:
       if i not in user:
         data = User(user =name, ID=i)
         db.session.add(data)
         db.session.commit()
         print("User record updated successfully!")
```